# Task : Find unique elements in an array. Count their occurrences. Find the numbers that occur less than 10 times in an array of 5000 elements

Tags: python-3.x

I tried a few solutions : 
1.)

```
 uniqueValues, indexList,occurCount = np.unique(desired_array, 
return_index=True, return_counts=True)  
print(uniqueValues,indexList,occurCount)
```

However the `indexList` only gives first occurrence of a number. For example : if num 33 occurred at 20,56,3000, indexList would only show that it occurred at 20. Since 33 occurs less than 10 times, i.e 3 times, I need all the locations.

2.) I decided to use dictionary to find all the index locations. But this is not working.

```
for i in range(5000): 
     ...:     if not d.get(i): 
     ...:         d[desired_array[i]]=[i]   
     ...:     else:  
     ...:         indices = d[desired_array[i]]  
     ...:         indices.append(i)
```

Comment: This worked for step 1:  d={}

for i in range(1250):         
    var=desired_array[i]  
    if not d.get(var):  
        d[var]=[] 
         #    print(var)       
    s=d[var]  
    s.append(i) 

print(d)

Answer (score 0):

This jobs screams for [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

desired_array = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 5, 3]
result = Counter(desired_array)
print(result)
```

This will print out the unique elements and the count of occurrences:

```
Counter({3: 3, 1: 2, 2: 1, 5: 1})
```

---

You can replace

```
for i in range(1250):
    var = desired_array[i]
    if not d.get(var):
        d[var] = []
    # print(var)
    s = d[var]
    s.append(i)
```

with

```
for i in range(1250):
    var = desired_array[i]
    d.setdefault(var, []).append(i)
```

According to the documentation [dict.setdefault(key, default)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

> If key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert key with a value of default and return default. default defaults to None.

---

To write a csv file it's best to use the standard `csv.Writer` class:

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(someiterable)
```

If you want to write the key/value pairs of your dict to the csv file you need to write something like:

```
with open('some.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for k, v in desired_array.items():
        writer.writerow((k, v))
```

Comment: for i in range(1250):         
    var=desired_array[i]  
    if not d.get(var):  
        d[var]=[] 
         #    print(var)       
    s=d[var]  
    s.append(i) 

print(d)

positives =  [x for x in d if x > 0 and len(d[x]) < 5]
print(positives)

d[28]=[]
for i in range(0,8):  
    d[28].extend(d[positives[i]]) #closest average value
    d.pop(positives[i],None)

negatives = [x for x in d if x <= 0 and len(d[x]) < 5]
print(negatives)

d[-28]=[]
for negative in negatives:   
    d[-28].extend(d[negative]) #closest average value 
    d.pop(negative,None) 
print(d)

Comment: I managed to get this working in the above code. Cannot yet figure formatting. But now I am struggling with saving dictionary to .csv file.

Comment: @JuieShetye you cannot add code formatting to comments - it would be better to edit your question